# How to fix Face4 to Face3

Tags: javascript, three.js

I found the old code, it almost works.

```
var geom = new THREE.Geometry();
geom.vertices = testRect.verts();

for ( var i = 0; i < verts.length; i+=4 ) {
    geom.faceVertexUvs[0].push([
        new THREE.Vector2(1.0 - ((verts[i].x - testRect.x) / testRect.width), 1.0 - ((verts[i].z - testRect.y) / testRect.height)),
        new THREE.Vector2(1.0 - ((verts[i+1].x - testRect.x) / testRect.width), 1.0 - ((verts[i+1].z - testRect.y) / testRect.height)),
        new THREE.Vector2(1.0 - ((verts[i+2].x - testRect.x) / testRect.width), 1.0 - ((verts[i+2].z - testRect.y) / testRect.height)),
        new THREE.Vector2(1.0 - ((verts[i+3].x - testRect.x) / testRect.width), 1.0 - ((verts[i+3].z - testRect.y) / testRect.height))
    ]);
}
for ( var i=0, vl=verts.length; i<vl; i+=4) {

    geom.faces.push(new THREE.Face4(i, i+1, i+2, i+3));
}
```

I found how to fix it (`Face4` to `Face3`)

```
THREE.Face4 = function ( a, b, c, d, normal, color, materialIndex ) {

    return new THREE.Face3( a, b, c, normal, color, materialIndex );

};
```

But it seems that there are not enough polygons http://dt-byte.ru/fea28697.png

Tried to do so

```
for ( var i=0, vl=verts.length; i<vl; i+=4) {
    geom.faces.push(new THREE.Face4(i, i+1, i+2, i+3));
    geom.faces.push(new THREE.Face4(i, i+3, i+2, i+1));
}
```

But something did not help (

Help solve this problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a geometry is defined by the quad (A, B, C, D), then the same geometry can be draw by the 2 triangles (A, B, C) and (A, C, D).

[image: quad to triangles]

Adapt the code somehow like this:

```
for ( var i=0, vl=verts.length; i<vl; i+=4) {

    geom.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( i, i+1, i+2 ) );
    geom.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( i, i+2, i+3 ) );
}
```